# Form color in design time doesn't affected

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-10.4-sydney

I have installed the IDE Delphi 10.4 recently, and when i opened the work project, the color of the form wasn't the same as setted in the palette. This is hapenning in every project, even in the one news projects or forms.

Someone already experienced this? How can i fix?

*In FireMonkey projects, the color is setted normally.

[image: The property color in the palette is clLime, but the form isn't affected.]

Comment: Strange..., for me the color setting affects the form immediately when I change it. Delphi 10.4 Community Edition. VCL project.

Comment: Yes, it happened when i installed Delphi. My edtion is Enterprise. If no one knows it, i will reinstall Delphi again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the patches 1, 2 and 3 from GetIt Package Manager. And the color in the form at design time is working perfectly.